# issue when sending a multipart post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-post, multipartform-data, hapi.js

I am using js to handle post request with multipart/form-data. When a post request is sent from client with multipart/form-data, it always returns bad request error. When I send request via postman, it gives me the error: "invalid multipart payload format when sending a multipart post request". Whichever call method I use, there is no action on server side.

```
{
        method: "POST",
        path: "/uploadFile",
        config: {
            payload: {
                output: "stream",
                parse: true,
                allow: "multipart/form-data"
            },
            handler: (request, reply) => {
                console.log("get into handler");
                let data = request.payload;
                if (data.file) {
                    let name = data.file.hapi.filename;
                    console.log(name);
                } else {
                    console.log("no data");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The client side code is like this:

```
$http({
               method: 'POST',
               url: serviceURL
               headers: {
                   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--xxxxSEPARATIONxxxx--'
               },
               data: formData
           });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using angular framework for the client side.
According to my experience, change 'Content-Type' to undefined in the headers, the browser will set the correct format for it. Also add transformRequest: angular.identity
Reference [this](http://www.uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs/) link.

Your code should look like this:

```
 $http({

       method: 'POST',
       url: serviceURL
       headers: {
           'Content-Type': undefined
       },
       transformRequest: angular.identity,
       data: formData
   });
```

Hope this work for you.

Comment: I am pretty new to AngularJS. Figured it out with help from my colleague by the same solution. Thank you though!